# How change color selected row in tableView javafx

Tags: css, javafx

I have a TableView clear. 
I have an button1, when I click this I added a row in my tableView and I select the row. This row is in red by the line css :

```
.table-row-cell:selected {-fx-background-color: red;}
```

Next, I have a button2, and I would like that when I click on the button2, the background color on my row selected change in blue.

Help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code into your **.css** file:

```
   #blue_cell .table-row-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

then add this into your java file

```
button2.setOnAction(e ->  productsTable.setId("blue_cell"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways for changing the values of properties in css from java code.

You can define a look-up color in css and use `setStyle()` method in java like that :

```
.table-view  {
-selected-color:red;
}
.table-row-cell:selected{
    -fx-background-color: -selected-color;
}
```

Then use `setStyle()` method :

```
 button2.setOnAction(e ->  table.setStyle("-selected-color:blue;"));
```